# Powershell charting

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to create a pie chart for number of SQL instances based on each version. For example , 2012 - 3 instances, 2008 - 2 instances, 2005 - 1 instance. Can anyone please help me on how to achieve this in pie chart.

The code is below:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization"
$scriptpath = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
#frame
$MemoryUsageChart2 = New-object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart
$MemoryUsageChart2.Width = 500
$MemoryUsageChart2.Height = 400
$MemoryUsageChart2.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::White
#header
[void]$MemoryUsageChart2.Titles.Add("No.SQL Instances")
$MemoryUsageChart2.Titles[0].Font = "segoeuilight,20pt"
$MemoryUsageChart2.Titles[0].Alignment = "Bottomright"

$chartarea = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea
$chartarea.Name = "ChartArea1"
$MemoryUsageChart2.ChartAreas.Add($chartarea)
[void]$MemoryUsageChart2.Series.Add("data2")

$MemoryUsageChart2.Series["data2"].ChartType = [System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType]::Pie
$SQL= @{SQLA=2012; SQLB=2012; SQLC=2008; SQLD=2005;SQLE=2005 ;SQLF=2000}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed resolve it using the below code, we have to group the hash table and get the counts of each instances and load it in the X and Y axis to get the pie chart :

```
    $MemoryUsageChart2.Series["data2"][“PieLabelStyle”] = “Outside” 
    $MemoryUsageChart2.Series["data2"][“PieLineColor”] = “Black” 
    $MemoryUsageChart2.Series["data2"][“PieDrawingStyle”] = "Concave”         
 $ht = $SQL.Values | group
            $x = $ht | select -ExpandProperty Name
            $y = $ht | select -ExpandProperty Count
            $i = 0
    $x | Foreach-object {$MemoryUsageChart2.Series["data2"].Points.AddXY("$($_ +(-$y[$i]))", $y[$i]); $i++ }
               $MemoryUsageChart2.SaveImage("C:\Virtual_Memory_Usage.png","png")
```